# Angular 4 file upload in form post

Tags: angular

Hi In a form I have several HTML controls and one file upload control. I’m filling all HTML controls with some text as well as one file for file upload.now I need to post all these data and file to my api.Can any one help me how to do this in angular 4

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng2-file-upload on Angular side.
   In your angular component, add

```
 this.uploadUrl = environment.baseApiUrl + '/api/file/Upload';
   this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: this.uploadUrl });

   this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) =>{

                var formData = [{‘your data’:’your data value’}];
                item.formData.push({ fileData: formData});

            };
```

Then in web api, add a controller like below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/file")]
    public class FileUploadController : ApiController    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FileUpload()
        {

            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "Media content error");
            }

            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            if(provider!=null && provider.Contents.Count>1)
            {
                //Your form data;
                var fileDataBuffer = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                 String fileDataJson = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileDataBuffer);

               //Your uploaded file
               var file = provider.Contents[1]; 
               var fileBuffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();


            }
            else
            {

                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "Invalid file");
            }


        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was as below :

In The html file get an input for the file

```
    <p >
      <label for="idFile" class="label-file">Choisir un Fichier</label>
      <input id="idFile" class="input-file" type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
    </p>
```

And in your ts write the method file change to get data

```
  fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      this.file = fileList[0];
     }
  }
```

Then you should post a formData containing your file and your data like this

```
  private docToFormData(doc) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', doc.file, doc.file.name);
    formData.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(doc)], {type: "application/json"}));
    return formData;
  }

  submitDocument(doc): Observable<any> {

    let formData = this.docToFormData(doc);
    return this._http.post(this._http.backendURL.submitDocument, formData)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        // TODO : return res.json and update back to return doc dto
        return res;
      });
  }
```

In my case doc is an object with metadata

I hope this could help.